# Python PIL: Can't iterate over folder?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have the following code working to compare two images:

```
path_one = filedialog.askopenfilename()
path_two = ("D:/QUIZ/folder1/folder2/1101Def.bmp")

image_one = Image.open(path_one)
image_two = Image.open(path_two)

diff = ImageChops.difference(image_one, image_two)

if diff.getbbox():
    print("images are different")
else:
    print("images are the same")
```

This simple code it's working without any problem.

Now I'm trying to take on the first image and check on a folder with thousands of images if one similar image it's there.

To do that i'm storing all the image names inside a list using glob and then try to iterate this way:

```
imagelist = []
os.chdir("i_denti")
for file in glob.glob("*.bmp"):
    listaimagens.append(file)


for x in imagelist:
    print(x)
    path_two = ("D:/QUIZ/folder1/folder2/"+str(x))
    image_two = Image.open(path_two)
    diff = ImageChops.difference(image_one, image_two)
    if diff.getbbox():
        print("a imagem "+str(x)+" é diferente")
    else:
        print("a imagem "+str(x)+" é a correcta")
        return image1._new(image1.im.chop_difference(image2.im))
```

With this code, i got an error

```
ValueError: images do not match
```

Anyone can help me and say why the code don't work inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when ImageChops.difference returns a ValueError, that means the image formats are different. You can run this to find out which files have this problem

```
imagelist = []
os.chdir("i_denti")
for file in glob.glob("*.bmp"):
    listaimagens.append(file)


for x in imagelist:
    print(x)
    path_two = ("D:/QUIZ/folder1/folder2/"+str(x))
    image_two = Image.open(path_two)
    if image_one.getbands() != image_two.get_bands():
        print("Bands {} and {} don't match".format(image_one.getbands(),image_two.getbands()))
        continue
    if image_one.size != image_two.size:
        print("Sizes {} and {} don't match".format(image_one.size,image_two.size))
        continue
    diff = ImageChops.difference(image_one, image_two)
    if diff.getbbox():
        print("a imagem "+str(x)+" é diferente")
    else:
        print("a imagem "+str(x)+" é a correcta")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but that wasn't the problem. The loop was breaking, but I figured out what was missing. I've added a try to workaround.

Anyway I want to thank you because after I tested your code I realized what was missing.

Comment: I fixed the code this way:

    try:
        diff = ImageChops.difference(image_one, image_two)
    except ValueError:
        print("erro")

    try:
        if diff.getbbox():
            print("a imagem "+str(x)+" é diferente")
            break
        else:
            print("a imagem "+str(x)+" é a correcta")
    except:
        pass